# Liferay Help - One portal instance, multiple organizations, mapped to multiple domains

Tags: liferay

1) I need help in setting up the liferay portal instance with multiple domains.
I have one portal instance with multiple organizations ( for example: abc org, xyz org, etc)
I want to map these organizations to different domains (for example: abc.com, xyz.com, etc)

I know that multiple portal instances with different company name (different companyId's) can be mapped through admin login in liferay, 
BUT
need help with the above mentioned setup: one instance-multiple org-mapped to multiple domains

2) If I use multiple instances, will this make performance issue in liferay?
Considering if we go with 1000 organizations with their respective domains mapped.

Answer (score 0):

1st question, checkout [Virtual Hosting](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Virtual+Hosting) on Liferay's web site.
2nd question, from my points of view, running 1000 micro websites on a single portal instances will definitely hit performance.

Answer (score 0):

We created a custom Liferay application that enables a company to sell products to customers. These customers also have access to whatever they bought via Liferay. A customer can have multiple users that access the portal through this customer account. So we tried adding an organization in Liferay for each customer, but this soon proved to be a very big performance hit. Liferay is able to handle 10's and maybe 100's of organizations, but 1000's and 10000's is too much. So I guess you'll possibly need multiple Liferay servers to handle 1000 mini-sites.